# Provision a 2013 list using a lookup with content in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012, app

I have a list, List A, which contains a lookup column to List B. When I deploy these lists I pr epopulate the lookup list (List B) with some sample items.

I also want to deploy List A with some sample Items, including the lookup Column's. Can this be pre populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. In the following XML, Category is a lookup field. The format for the lookup field value is `<item id>;#<item title>`

```
<Row>
  <Field Name="ID">1</Field>
  <Field Name="Title">Chai</Field>
  <Field Name="ProductID">1</Field>
  <Field Name="Category">1;#Beverages</Field>
  <Field Name="QuantityPerUnit">10 boxes x 20 bags</Field>
  <Field Name="UnitPrice">18</Field>
  <Field Name="UnitsInStock">39</Field>
  <Field Name="UnitsOnOrder">0</Field>
  <Field Name="ReorderLevel">10</Field>
  <Field Name="Discontinued">False</Field>
</Row>
```

Comment: Much Appreciated Rob.